# what do you think about read performance in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I read a lot of articles. Many says cassandra is fast in read many says cassandra is slow. I mean a lot of big companies uses cassandras. If it were slow, they dont would use it or i am wrong ?

Maybe I want to search an Article by id and I have 10 million rows, would it take more than 1-2 seconds ?

Whats your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work with hundreds of companies who use Cassandra on a daily basis and most of these companies do things on internet scale.

Most of their SLAs require ~6 millisecond read latency 95% of the time at peak app traffic. For that reason, a 2-second latency is a read timeout in Cassandra terms.

For those who say it is slow, I'll let the tech giants do the talking for Cassandra -- Apple, Netflix, Uber, Visa, FedEx, Sony, GE, Expedia and the list goes on and on and on. :)